# Мониторинг веб-сервера на Python

Tags: python, linux, сеть, веб-сервер

Написал мониторинг для проверки веб-серверов на предмет падения, чтобы мне не клиенты сообщали о падении, а я первый об этом узнавал, на текущий момент - это 14 серверов. Делаю 1 пинг через os.system() и проверяю статус 200 ОК через requests.get() на страницу авторизации (стоят панели ISP/Plesk). В случае срабатывания - отправляется емейл на номер@sms.mtslife.ru и мне приходит смска на телефон. Скрипт запускается по крону на отдельном серваке каждую минуту и пишет лог в файл. Хотел бы узнать - какими способами можно еще проверять статус сервера, кроме этих двух? И как ускорить процесс получения сигнала? Потому что смска через МТС может идти дольше минуты.

Comment: а почему вы не пользуетесь стандартными решениями в этой области  - [zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/ru/) или [nagios](https://www.nagios.org/) ?

Comment: Можно отправлять сообщение в телеграм

Answer (score 2):

> И как ускорить процесс получения сигнала?

Отправлять SMS-ку через телефон или 3G-GSM-модем. Это будет намного быстрее чем передача через `email-to-sms` шлюз оператора.